# Data Transfer Object

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

In my architecture, in my DAO layer, i want to convert Entity`(javax.persistence.Entity)` to Pure Entity.for example imagine I have Entity Like this:

```
    @Entity
    public class DAOImp(){

    @Id
    private int id;
    .
    .
    .//getter and setter
    }
```

transfer to This Class:

```
public class DAOData{
 private int id;
.
.
.//getter and setter
}
```

The Problem occure when this is mapping field in my DAOImpl class.for emample imagine one of my filed in DAOImp class is :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="kc5tnx")
    private List<Kc5add> kc5adds;
```

i don,t know how can i handle this problem . i don,t know how can i Transfer this entity to DAOData.
Could you please tell how can i fix this problem?

Comment: [**JPA/EJB3 KILLED THE DAO**](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/jpa_ejb3_killed_the_dao)

Answer (score 1):

You have to implements your class with serializable

```
public class DAOData  implements Serializable
{
 private int id;
.
.
.//getter and setter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create converter to transfer you data between your entity(DAOImp) and Data transfer object(DAOData) and manually transfer only POJO data to DTO.

for example:

```
public class DaoConverter {

  public static DaoData convertToDTO(DaoImpl daoImpl) {
    DaoData daoDataDTO = new DaoData();
    daoDataDTO.setId(daoImpl.getId());
    ...
    return daoDataDTO;
  }

}
```

Comment: yes,,, i know this rule.
but i don,t know how can i write  and convert "Mapping Field" .
could you please write the Equivalent of 
@OneToMany(mappedBy="kc5tnx")
    private List<Kc5add> kc5adds;
field in "DAOData" class?

Comment: It must be private List<Kc5add> kc5adds;
Can you write your exception?
Does Kc5add also entity object?
Maybe Kc5add is proxy object. Or maybe you need to parse all objects in list and detach it first like:

`for(Kc5add kc5add : Kc5addList) {
 kc5add = entityManager.detach(kc5add);
 DAOData.getkc5addList().add(kc5add);
}`